# 100 Most Used Strings in File

Tags: perl, file, sorting, hash, cpu-word

How can I find the top 100 most used strings (words) in a `.txt` file using Perl? So far I have the following:

```
use 5.012;
use warnings;

open(my $file, "<", "file.txt");

my %word_count;
while (my $line = <$file>) {
  foreach my $word (split ' ', $line) {
     $word_count{$word}++;
  } 
} 

for my $word (sort keys %word_count) {
  print "'$word': $word_count{$word}\n";
}
```

But this only counts each word, and organizes it in alphabetical order. I want the top 100 most frequently used words in the file, sorted by number of occurrences. Any ideas?

*Related: [Count number of times string repeated in files perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5571016/count-number-of-times-string-repeated-in-file-perl)*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From reading the fine *perlfaq4*(1) manpage, one learns [how to sort hashes by value](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-do-I-sort-a-hash-(optionally-by-value-instead-of-key)%3f). So try this. It’s rather more idiomatically “perlian” than your approach.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl    
use v5.12;
use strict;
use warnings;
use warnings FATAL => "utf8";
use open qw(:utf8 :std);

my %seen;
while (<>) {
    $seen{$_}++ for split /\W+/;  # or just split;
}

my $count = 0;
for (sort {
        $seen{$b} <=> $seen{$a}
                  ||
           lc($a) cmp lc($b)    # XXX: should be v5.16's fc() instead
                  ||
              $a  cmp  $b
     } keys %seen)
{
    next unless /\w/;
    printf "%-20s %5d\n", $_, $seen{$_};
    last if ++$count > 100;
}
```

When run against itself, the first 10 lines of output are:

```
seen                     6
use                      5
_                        3
a                        3
b                        3
cmp                      2
count                    2
for                      2
lc                       2
my                       2
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, which part(s) of the answer specifically requires Perl v5.12?  The `use warnings FATAL => "utf8";`, or the `use open qw(...)`, or both?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I thought very heavily about that, for the answer is nothing at all. I put it in simply because I think that every Perl source unit should explicitly declare the actual version it ran under. This is because of how surprisingly volatile the language’s subtly shifting syntax and semantics have been since it hit the double digits in release numbers. The `open` pragma premièred in v5.6, albeit without yet a version number. I don’t recall when utf8 warnings first appeared, nor when warnings were first fatalizable in this fashion; I doubt this was any later than v5.8, though.

Comment: @tchrist: Question: When running the program against my text file, I am getting the error: `Use of uninitialized value $_ in split`. Any ideas of why?

Comment: @Jae That can’t happen. It is impossible to enter the `while` loop with `$_` holding the undefined value, as that is what it is testing for. Therefore, the `split` is guaranteed always to have a defined value with which to work. Perhaps you have not copied the whole program in full, but only patched your own with partial updates, and forgotten or misunderstood something.

Comment: @tchrist: Yes. Sorry about that. I did patch my program. After copy.pasting yours, it worked. Thanks very much!